# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'routes[state.index].key')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am working on an app using react-native and react-navigation and when executinng the code:

```
            const reset = StackActions.reset({
                    actions: [
                            NavigationActions.navigate({
                                    index: 0,
                                    routeName: "intervention",
                                    params: {
                                            button: true
                                    }
                            })
                    ],
            });
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(reset);
```

below I have the following error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'routes[state.index].key')

my first instinct was to do a grep but this was the result:

```
[jjulien@localhost appRoot]$ grep -r "routes[state.index].key"
[jjulien@localhost appRoot]$
```

I really have no idea where does it come from I search here on Stack OverFlow and on the GitHub of stack Navigation but no luck. Does somebody have an int where to search for or anything really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't touched React Native or `react-navigation` but I'll take a shot!

It looks like you have `index` set in the wrong spot.

Taking a peek at the [StackActions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset) and [NavigationActions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html) docs, it looks like `index` belongs in the object you pass to `reset` rather than `navigate`. Try switching your code to be like this:

```
const reset = StackActions.reset({
                    index: 0,
                    actions: [
                            NavigationActions.navigate({
                                    routeName: "intervention",
                                    params: {
                                            button: true
                                    }
                            })
                    ],
            });
```

Just as an added funfact, the code you were looking for isn't in your own codebase, rather it comes from the [StackRouter.js](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-core/blob/master/src/routers/StackRouter.js) file from `react-navigation`. When you run that `StackActions.reset` action, `StackRouter` later looks for the new value of `index` in its internal state. Because `index` wasn't defined in your code the router can't find the entry in its history that it should be referring to.

Hope that does it! :D